# django cmsplugin_contact

Tags: django, django-cms

I have successfully installed the django cmsplugin_contact, but what I really need is for the form to save to the database. I have been reading up on newForms, but the python file structure which is implied is rather different, so I don't seem to make it work.

Any clues as to how to easily make it save to the database?

I've tried several different things, but no good results have come out of it.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The contact plugin is excellent by the way, and forget the documentation, just read the code, it's pretty simple.

This thread is old but I like the question and I think I need such a thing too, so here's an answer:

You could make a new contact app, smartcontact, which extends the default contact plugin...

The contact plugin uses this form:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    subject = forms.CharField(required=False)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
```

Then all you would need to do is make a cms_plugins.py file inside that app folder, and extend the contacts app to inherit that behavior and just fix what you want to change.  So check out this untested code...:

```
from cmsplugin_contact.cms_plugins import ContactPlugin
from smartcontact.models import SmartContact #<-- your SmartContact model.

class SmartContactPlugin(ContactPlugin):

    def send(self, form, site_email):
        sc = SmartContact()
        sc.from_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        sc.subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        sc.content = form.cleaned_data['content']
        #and then if you want to also send email, uncomment this to also call
        #parent's version.
        #ContactPlugin.send(self, form, site_email)
```

So I guess then you need a model to save that into, and well that would be easy from the fields needed above.

Don't forget to add your new app to settings.py and stick `plugin_pool.register_plugin(SmartContactPlugin)` at the end of your new cms_plugins.py file.

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin doesn't have any documentation, you may as well skip the plugin and just use your own view code hooked via a CMS App that is assigned to your page.